# NSURLProtocol chain?

Tags: nsurlprotocol

Can we use such a chain?

for example, I know urls like abc://wwww.example.com will be handled by a subclass of NSURLProtocol. But it is from a third party library and I do not have the source code to modify the response. So I provide another subclass of NSURLProtocol to handle urls like xyz://www.example.com. I am able to intercept and change urls from abc to xyz. In my own startLoading(), I changed the urls back from xyz to abc and use NSURLSession to send request to abc://www.example.com but got error and looks like the request did not go through the third party NSURPProtocol subclass.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLProtocol` subclasses are only registered globally for `NSURLConnection`.  For `NSURLSession`, the registration is per-session.

If you want to register an `NSURLProtocol` in such a way that it would affect third-party libraries, the only way I'm aware of is by swizzling all of the session creation methods on `NSURLSession` and wrapping them with code that injects your custom protocol into the configuration on the way in.

Comment: This is very useful - never know there is such a difference. Thank you!